# Question about notation in proof of limit comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, intuition

In a book I came across the following:

> **Theorem: Limit Comparison Test**
>
> Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ have positive terms and that $\frac{\color{blue}{ a_n }}{\color{blue}{ b_n }} \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $L \not = 0$.
>
> If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ is convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent.

I'm getting a bit lost in the notation details. Question: What are $\color{blue}{ a_n }, \color{blue}{ b_n }$ in the part where it says " ... $\frac{\color{blue}{ a_n }}{\color{blue}{ b_n }} \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ..." ?

To my understanding, $a_n, b_n$ are the n-th *partial sums* of the two series, which is not the same as the n-th *term* of the respective series.

If then the ratio between the two partial sums is tending towards  a constant, it makes sense that they have both the same convergence status. And this allows to deduce the convergence status of the series.

Is that what is meant here? Or do we actually check the ratio between the n-th terms?

Comment: They are the $n^{th}$ terms.

Comment: I found a good additional intuition on this test: "Here we are comparing how fast the terms grow. If the limit is positive, then the terms are growing at the same rate, so both series converge or diverge together." From http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/math/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/SeriesTests/limit_comparison.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not what is meant there. In the expression $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$, $a_n$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, and $b_n$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> term of the sequence $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. There are no partial sums here.

Comment: OK, that's good to know and helps to clear my misunderstanding. So we are comparing the ratio of the n-th terms basically. The idea is then that the larger n gets, then the ratio converges towards a constant. But somehow I can't follow why this means the series have the same convergence status.

Comment: They have the same convergence status assuming that $L\in(0,\infty)$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n}<2L$ if $n$ is large enough, and therefore, since $a_n<2Lb_n$, the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ implies the convergence of the series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. On the other hand, $\frac{a_n}{b_n}>\frac L2$ if $n$ is large enough, and therefore, since $b_n<\frac2La_n$, the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ implies the convergence of the series  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$.